# Multiple Marriages in a family in the same year

Tags: rituals, marriage

If two brothers of same family get married in two dates and two places in the same samvatsara (an year in Hindu calendar), will this be auspicious or unauspicious ? If it's unauspicious, what is the solution ?

Comment: Raama, Lakshamana, Bharata, Shatrughan got marry on same day.

Comment: That is Ramayana,the whole journey of Sriraama and Seete runs in misary,Lakshmana spent time in forest,Bharat though he was in Ayodhya not sat on throne,father Dasharata seen all these at the end of life,was this auspicious ?

Comment: I heard from people's around me that,once a marriage done in a family,there should not be another marriage or auspicious function within a year or Samvatsara (Yugadi festival to next Yugadi festival) in that family.But i need to know the astrological or vaidic shastra's reason.

Comment: Please do not forget that marriage of all 4 brothers were performed under guidance of **Rishi Vashishta** who was one of the **SaptraRishis** (highest level of Rishi that one can attain). Rishi Vashishta and Kull Guru of Janaka said marriage of 4 brothers will be gud then who can put question on that decision of those great sages of Treta Yuga..? You think people of Kali yuga has more knowledge than Great sages of Treta yuga..? Reall..? Please think again.. on whom you are putting question mark :) Besides all those miseries was just Leela of Lord Vishnu.. He is beyond auspicious and unauspic..

Comment: Iam agreeing your valuable comment and respecting.My question mark is on auspicious or unauspicious situation in my comment not on any role or icons or sages or their actions.My question is also on auspicious or unauspicious related to brother marriage rituals in different dates of year.There is lot of gap inbetween people of Kaliyuga,dwapara yuga,treta yuga and satyayuga people based on knowledge or atma gyan.Topic is going to Ramayana.Coming to my question,searching reason & solution for No 2 marriages in a year of family.Why not ?

Comment: Soul reason of mine to tell you about Rama's marraige was, If there is any chances unauspicious use to happen on marraige of all brother at same date, then those sages must have reccomend to postpond marraige of other brothers. If Sage Vashishta thinks there is no unauspicious in marrying mutiple brother then what left to worry about? People of Kali yuga are expert in spreading baseless roumors. But we can learn truth from history, can't we :)

Comment: Yes, your points are right.Your point of view of Brothers marriage in Ramayana performed on the same day with same auspicious time.But my question pointed on two different dates of a year.Example one brother marriage done in July month and second brother marriage done in August month of the same year.In south India specially in Karnataka Telangana and Andhra Pradesh i heard,its resulted unauspicious situation in the family if done twice or more in a year.This all in oral communication.This is a question of many.I believe Vaidic sanskar,shastra, astrology.These were gifted for human welfare

Comment: This custom may not have link to auspiciousness but more to domestic conditions of that period. Earlier there used to be joint family.  Bringing 2 or 3 brides in the same year may pose many practical difficulties like sharing of duties, sharing of available accommodation between newly married couples,etc @VEERANNA P BADIGER

Answer (score 3):

There is a general belief in Hinduism that we should give some gap between marriage of one member to another member in the same family. This also has a scriptural basis.

I could not find anything related to brothers marriage in same family but the general rule of giving a gap should be maintained. ( Bold emphasis mine)

From Narada Purana chapter 56 which talks about general astrology.

> 515. *Prohibitions in marriage* : A daughter's marriage should not be conducted for three seasons after a son's marriage, neither should be sacrament (for the change to married life, vrata). **When there has been an auspicious event, there shall not be another auspicious event closely following**.

So it is recommended to maintain a gap between two auspicious events like marriages and other sacraments.

For more detail, it's recommended to consult a knowledgeable astrologer for  next muhurta and conduct marriage.

Comment: Noted,my doubt was will it be dosha if auspicious  events followed by auspicious events,as it's happened in my own family ,since then unexpected suffering we experiencing